# Multiple File Upload Code for Django

Tags: python, django, file, upload

Ok. So I've come up with the following code after searching a lot of forums and other posts in Stackoverflow. First of all I've tried using `request.FILES.get('onefile')` but that only uploaded one file no matter how many I selected during the upload. So I've changed my code a bit to upload files with names like file1, file2, etc. The following are my codes, but I don't know why this is not working. No file is currently being uploaded and it shows an error listed under the following code.

**upload2.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="/index/multi/" enctype="multipart/form-data"> {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="file" name="onefile" multiple>

        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def upload2(request):
    return render(request, "upload2.html", {})

def multi(request):
    count = 1
    for x in request.FILES.getlist('onefile'):
        print request.FILES.getlist('onefile')
        def handle_uploaded_file(f):
            with open('/home/michel/django/upload/media/file' + count, 'wb+') as destination:
                for chunk in f.chunks():
                    destination.write(chunk)
        handle_uploaded_file(x)
        count = count + 1
    return HttpResponse('Uploaded!')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from index import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^upload2/$', views.upload2),
    url(r'^multi/$', views.multi),
]
```

**error**

```
TypeError at /index/multi/
cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/index/multi/
Django Version: 1.8.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
Exception Location: /home/michel/django/upload/index/views.py in handle_uploaded_file, line 32
```

I'm not sure whether I've missed something. Please let me know if you need anything else. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure whether I've missed something.

Yes : reading the error message - which tells you what the error is -, the traceback - which tells you where the error happened - and then re-reading your code. So you have:

> Exception Type: TypeError
>   Exception Value:
>   cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Which means you tried to concatenate a string and an integer (which Python does not allow for a quite obvious reason).

and

> Exception Location: /home/michel/django/upload/index/views.py in handle_uploaded_file, line 32

which means the error is in /home/michel/django/upload/index/views.py at line 32.

Line 32 of /home/michel/django/upload/index/views.py is :

```
with open('/home/michel/django/upload/media/file' + count, 'wb+') as destination:
```

Obviously, `'/home/michel/django/upload/media/file' + count` is the culprit. Now you just have to fix this, either making a string of `count` or using string formating - both explained in the FineManual(tm).

While you're at it, you may also want to read about the builtin `enumate(sequence)` function.

Comment: I feel very dumb. Thank you for taking your precious time to answer with so much details. I think I need to spend more time with Python instead of Django. I don't know a lot of functions in Python. I added str() as suggested by @chandu and it did the trick.

Comment: string formatting is the prefered solution in Python - if only for readability.

Answer (score 1):

It concatenate error,you cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects.

I thinks problem is at this line

```
'/home/michel/django/upload/media/file' + count
```

### Solution

```
'/home/michel/django/upload/media/file' + str(count)
```

Example:

```
a = 'test'
b = 1
c = a+b
Type Error: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

### solution:

```
a = 'test'
b = str(1) or '1'
c = a+b(works fine)
```